# How to set primary contact for a particular contact with multi contact numbers?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to set a primary contact of a person if i have multi contacts of that person . I went through this link [android contacts provider: how to set phone number primary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424407/android-contacts-provider-how-to-set-phone-number-primary)

Can anyone please elaborate the code?

Answer (score 0):

The Phone number is stored in Data table inside the contacts database. If you want one number to be the primary number, that record in the Data table has to marked as IS_PRIMARY and IS_SUPER_PRIMARY. To do this put 1 in the IS_PRIMARY and IS_SUPER_PRIMARY column. Something like this.

```
Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
mValues.put(Phone.IS_PRIMARY, 1);
mValues.put(Phone.IS_SUPER_PRIMARY, 1);
getContentResolver().update(uri, mValues, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA + "=?", new String[]{'<number>'});
```